# Installing IonCube on Ubuntu without root privileges

Tags: server, permissions, zend

I'm attempting to install IonCube loaders via the ionCube Loader Wizard.  I selected "local" and then on the next step, I get the following message:

> Please note that the following problem currently exists with the ionCube Loader installation:
>
> The necessary zend_extension line could not be found in the configuration.

I have researched how to correct this, however, every answer I have come across has resulted in permission denied errors.  My IT guy is out today and I don't have root permissions or access. I tried Derrick's answer to this question on Stackoverflow post [ionCube installation :: missing zend_extension CentOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745394/ioncube-installation-missing-zend-extension-centos)

I also tried installing without the Wizard and that's when I run into all sorts of permission issues.  Their documentation says:

> ### Installing to a remote UNIX/LINUX CLOUD, DEDICATED or VPS server
>
> 1. Upload the contents of this package to /usr/local/ioncube
> 2. Copy the loader-wizard.php script to the root web directory of a     configured domain on the server
> 3. Launch the Loader Wizard script in your browser. For example:     http://yourdomain/loader-wizard.php

I can't even make a directory in /usr/local/ nevermind copy the contents.  Does anyone know how I might be able to bypass the permission issues or install this another way?  OR, perhaps someone has a better idea to fix the Zend Extension error with minimal permissions.  Thanks in advance!